# How to pass the value from my form to another form?

Tags: php, forms

Hello  i cannot seem to pass the value from my form to another form .

To explain this i have 3 forms:

1. alldeals.php
2. stardealdesc.php
3. form.php

what i have have done is pass the values from alldeals.php to stardealdesc.php and it work fine. however in stardealdesc.php i have a button that when click will popup a form (form.php)
i wan to make use the values that is parse from alldeals.php to stardealdesc.php to be also parse to formp.php .

This is the pop up codes:

```
function Popup() {
window.open( 'form.php', "myWindow", 
"status = 1, height = 500, width = 500, resizable = 0" )
}

<form>
<input type="button" onClick="Popup()" value="Buy">
</form>
```

And this is the statement to get the values from alldeals.php

```
$cmeter = $_REQUEST['cmeter'];
```

which work fine but i want to take this value and display it in form.php

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean PASS not PARSE,

You need to store the saved form inputs into the session

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['form1_values'] = $_POST; // Submitted from form 1
$_SESSION['form2_values'] = $_POST; // Submitted from form 2
$_SESSION['form3_values'] = $_POST; // Submitted from form 3
```

Then you can refer to those values from any PHP script at any time until the session is cleared

Comment: Wheredo i place this ? stardealdesc?

Comment: Form 1 = alldeals.php, Form 2 = stardealdesc.php, Form 3 = form.php

Answer (score 0):

not sure about security terms, but if you want to pass the details on `form.php` that is displaying in pop window, then use that in url like `form.php?username=somename`

Comment: i want to pass the details in stardealdesc.php to form.The details from stardealdesc.php are actually being pass from alldeals.php using that method.

Comment: Yeah, i wouldn't use that - security reasons... sorry :(